# Disabling auto rotation for UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller, autorotate

I want to disable UIImagePickerView's auto rotation. So I used the following code:

```
UIDevice *currentDevice = [UIDevice currentDevice];


        [parentViewController presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];

        while ([currentDevice isGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications])
            [currentDevice endGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
```

It disables the ImagePickerView but it also disables the rotation of root view. But I want the auto rotation feature in my root view controller(or I want to disable auto rotation for only in my ImagePickerController). For clarification, before disabling the UIImagePickerController auto rotation, the auto rotation was active in my root view.

**UPDATES & Answer::**

I found the answer. Write the following code to enable auto rotation:

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
```

If you have any image processing (I had actually), call this method after completing all the image processing tasks. In my case, I called it before the image processing, and it didn't enable the orientation.

Answer (score -1):

This is how I did. UIImageViewController is a UIViewController which has a method called -(BOOL)shouldAutorotate;

What we can to do is to create a SubClass of UIImageViewController and over write the shouldAutorotate method. Let's say, our sub-class' name is MyImageViewController.

Then the MyImageViewController.h would look like-

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MyImageViewController : UIImagePickerController

@end
```

And the MyImageViewController.m file should look like-

```
#import "MyImagePickerViewController.h"

@interface MyImagePickerViewController ()

@end

@implementation MyImagePickerViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate{
    return NO;
}
@end
```

Now we are good to go! Rather than creating the UIImagePickerViewController, we can create MyImagePickerViewController in the parentViewController like-

```
MyImagePickerViewController *imagePicker = [[MyImagePickerViewController alloc] init];
[parentViewController presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
```

It will not autorotate as you set the shouldAutoRotate to NO;

Answer (score -1):

**Try this :**

```
@interface UIImagePickerController(addition)

@end
@implementation UIImagePickerController(addition)

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate{
    return NO;
}

@end
```